# Slider to show elements at specific values

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, slider

I want to have a jQuery/any slider that is similar to [this](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#default) one, but with little more functionality.

I will have elements in my HTML code, an image, text, and maybe some divs, which should be hidden by default, but when the slider reaches a specific value, the image/text/whatever should successively show up.

So at value 0, for example, only one image is shown, then at value 1 another one pops up, and so on.

Are there any pre-made jQuery plugins for this or how would I go about this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>jQuery Mobile Tutorial on Codeforest.net</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <style>
            #slider {
                margin: 10px;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            var img1 = $('<img\>').attr('src', 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/');
            var img2 = $('<img\>').attr('src', 'http://lorempixel.com/300/200/');
            var foto = $('#foto');

            foto.html(img1);

            $("#slider").slider({
                slide: function(event, ui) {
                    if (ui.value > 50) {
                        $('#foto').html(img2);
                    } else {
                        $('#foto').html(img1);
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="slider"></div>
        <div id="foto"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The jQueryUI slider has a build-in function to get the value when you slide. So you can get the value of your slider at anytime.

```
$("#slider").slider({
    slide: function(event, ui) {
       console.log(ui.value);
    } 
});
```

It shouldn't be that hard to append specific images at a certain point. You can also unhide your divs, or whatever you want. I've build build an example for you on JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/AVBWr/

**Edit: Make sure that you wrap it inside document.ready function like so:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var img1 = $('<img\>').attr('src', 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/');
    var img2 = $('<img\>').attr('src', 'http://lorempixel.com/300/200/');
    var foto = $('#foto');

    foto.html(img1);

    $("#slider").slider({
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.value > 50) {
                $('#foto').html(img2);
            } else {
                $('#foto').html(img1);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried to use your example (please see my MWE), but mine doesn't show anything. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Make sure that you wrap it inside a document.ready function  
Or load it on the bottom of your page.